# "AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'" using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i am working on Jupyter notebook and I am getting this error

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

after successfully running the commands

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dir(cv2)
```

which gives output as

```
['doc',
'file',
'loader',
'name',
'package',
'path',
'spec']
```

How can I read image in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Can you post complete error stack?

Comment: My guess is that you have created your own file called `cv2.py`.  That will get loaded first.

Comment: @sociopath here is complete error stack AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f34764732772> in <module>
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 img1path=r"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Image034"
----> 4 img1 = cv2.imread(img1path)
      5 plt.imshow(img1)

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'imread'

Comment: @TimRoberts i didn't creat any such file

Comment: Please do `import cv2` / `print(cv2.__file__)` / `print(cv2.__version__)`.

Comment: I assume your file name actually ends `Image034.png` or `Image034.jpg` and not just `Image034`.

Comment: yes, it's Image034.jpg

Comment: for print(cv2.__file__) it returns none as output

Comment: for print(cv2.__version__) i get  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-87e6d4ebee34> in <module>
      1 import cv2
      2 print(cv2.__file__)
----> 3 print(cv2.__version__)
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 img1path=r"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Image034.jpg"

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '__version__

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code snippet that read's image using cv2 and displays in python notebook

```
import cv2
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('/home/venkatesh/Pictures/my_image.jpg')
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: My code is similar to yours...I can't find where I did mistake     import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img1path=r"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Image034"
img1 = cv2.imread(img1path)
plt.imshow(img1)